# Immutable.fromJS performance issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I want to load about 10k records from my API - it's quite a big JSON, but it's not that big, I want to save it into a redux state as an immutable object:

```
case GET_ALL:
    return state.merge({
        data: action.response
    })
```

The problem is that it's very slow, becuase `action.response` (the 10k records object) is being converted to `Immutable` object. So even though I have nice catching on the backend side, the whole application is very slow because of this issue. Is there a way to deal with this?

Comment: Can you paste a snippet of action.response so we know the structure of the data

Comment: surely you don't need to make it all an immutable.js structure. i would cache the big data and feed parts into my state as-needed. perhaps you can live with Object.freeze or just not trashing state, but at any rate converting smaller chunks to genuine immutable.js pieces will solve your slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [seamless-immutable](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable). This library extends basic javascript objects instead of creating special ones.

For your use case I may be faster